# Not MiFI, but similar?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, rj-45, mifi

I already have MiFI but due to some reasons that I can't explain, WiFi isn't good enough for me, I need to connect via RJ45. So I'm wondering if there is any device that takes my 3G enabled SIM and allows me to use a LAN/RJ45 connection?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm a little confused on your question. Do you not like WiFi because of the potential security issues with packet sniffers or is it because you are around annoying people with Cordless Phones?

Comment: If you're worried about latency with WiFi, then I would think that a 3G connection would be the point of latency if you manage to find a RJ45 connection to your computer.

Comment: Your speed will always be determined by your weakest connection and is in most cases the 3G link.

Comment: Do you have 4G LTE in your area?

Comment: Honestly, I've been tethering with a 4G LTE device to my laptop and constantly get 2MB/s download speeds and usually 384KB/s to 512KB/s upload speeds. I will tether sometimes using my USB cable and other times as a Hotspot (same concept as MiFi). I get the exact same speeds from both hardwire and wireless connections.

Answer (score 1):

I've used devices before that do exactly this, however all the ones that I can find require you to get a router and USB modem separately. I know that CradlePoint makes some, however you'll have to buy a USB 3G modem (~$50) to go with one.

Comment: Most of the non-mifi type 3G sharing routers do exactly this, they have a usb slot for a 3G dongle, plus wifi and ethernet.

Comment: I'm not talking about 3G dongle, but 3G SIM.

Answer (score 1):

This will take a 3G SIM and you can connect a RJ45 Ethernet Cable.

Digi Connect WAN 3G IA EV-DO

[image]

Comment: Great, where can I buy it from? Will it work internationally with any SIM?